# How to know which cell is tapped

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

How can I get the index path of the cell which has been selected from tableView?

I do not have the index path also. I only have the tableView object with me.

Comment: Did you build the tableViewController using the template? In there you can find tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: which is called when a cell is touched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use delegate's method tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
this is the only proper way of obtaining the selected cell.